# Input Variable SAS Macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

```
%let dsin = pre_finalized;
data _null_;
set &dsin. (obs=1);
```

I also tried

```
%let dsin = data.pre_finalized;
```

Is the above the correct way to call my code. It is not the full code. But I am unsure if I am calling the dataset correctly. I keep on getting error logs. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  This could work, I suppose, but it just depends on what you're doing.  Include errors/etc. in the question.

Comment: Macro code still has to generate valid code. What does your working code look like without macro variables?

Comment: Can you please show what error are you getting to get a better idea of the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you are trying to call a dataset using a macro variable.
Below is the code which i quickly tested and its working.
Please see if this helps.

```
%let data=sashelp.class;

data abc;
set &data. (obs=1);
run;
```